# How in angular detect how many components in ng-content?

Tags: angular

Now I have two components

```
//app-row-two
<div>
  <div x-col><ng-content select="[slot=1]"></ng-content></div>
  <div x-col><ng-content select="[slot=2]" ></ng-content></div>
</div>
//app-row-three
<div>
  <div x-col><ng-content select="[slot=1]"></ng-content></div>
  <div x-col><ng-content select="[slot=2]" ></ng-content></div>
  <div x-col><ng-content select="[slot=3]" ></ng-content></div>
</div>
```

For two and three columns. And when I use it need to write slot="1" etc.
Is a way to merge it into one component  that detect how many components in ng-content and create columns ?

Answer (score 2):

Angular has a decorator that enables a component to detect and query the inner children, it's the `ContentChildren` decorator.

I created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/content-children-sample?file=src/app/container.component.ts) working sample using it to count how many children are inserted inside the ng-content. You can use a directive or a base abstract class.

Here's the [Angular Docs link](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren#description) on this approach.

To be detectable, you need to tell Angular how it will find the children, in this case, I am using a directive:

```js
@Directive({ selector: "[option]" })
export class Option {}

@Component({
  selector: "container",
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <strong>I have {{ childrensLength }} childrens</strong>
  `
})
export class ContainerComponent {
  @ContentChildren(Option) options: QueryList<Option>;

  get childrensLength(): number {
    return this.options ? this.options.length : 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<container>
    <div option>I am queryable!</div>
    <div option>Me too!</div>
    <div option>Me as well...</div>
    <div>I am not queryable</div>
</container>
```

Output:

[image: Output sample with the rendered result at browser]